# Turn Undefined Property Access Into an Error

Tags: flowtype

I noticed I can define a type for a function and accidentally access properties on that function

```
type FakeType = {}
type aFunc = string => number

const b: aFunc = () => 1
const a: FakeType = b.whatTheHeck // Flow makes "whatTheHeck" any type
```

Is there a way to make this an error in Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why Flow doesn't error on this automatically, but what you can do is declare `aFunc` as a callable object, rather than just a function, e.g.

```
type aFunc = {
  (string): number,
};
```

([On flowtype.com/try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYghgawgFXNAvFA3gXwFCiRRwwCuAdgMZSZZ5RQAUAzsAE4CW5A5gJQBcUcqQC2AIwhsANHhwBuPHkoB7cqyhjBJCtUyNeNAHxQAjEtXq4g+ElRFMYgHQB3ABZxgyVxAASESghQAPRBsAA2ys5QIogQzFAARG4eXr7+CAnE5CBQhBCKYowJCbxyQA))